# Limits of API Calls to Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, integration, data

I want to send data daily to Salesforce. I am building a custom integration. I have tested with Postman the API Rest of Salesforce and it works well, but I have doubts the limits of integrations to Salesforce.

- How many records can be sent to Salesforce ?
- How many records can be consulted to Salesforce ?
- How many API calls can we make to Salesforce daily?

I have seen, the maxinum records returned is 2000. There is a Workaround (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339353&type=1&mode=1)

There is a maximum of API Calls from Salesforce (per user), but to Salesforce?

> *For Salesforce Professional and Enterprise, each organization receives a total of 1,000 API calls per user in a 24-hour period, up
>   to a maximum of 1,000,000 API calls (for organizations with 15,000+
>   Salesforce licenses). Salesforce Unlimited has a 5,000 API calls per
>   user limit, up to a maximum of unlimited API calls.*

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How many records can be sent to Salesforce ?

200 per transaction is the general limit for most APIs. The Bulk API supports up to 10,000 records per file.

> How many records can be consulted to Salesforce ?

As much storage space as you have allocated. Most records cost 2KB each, so 500 records per MB of storage. For a Developer Edition, this is a maximum of 2,500 records. For most other editions, a minimum of 500,000 records; the more licenses you have, the more data you can store.

> How many API calls can we make to Salesforce daily?
>
> ---
>
> There is a maximum of API Calls from Salesforce (per user), but to Salesforce?

The limits are organization-wide, but calculated per user. For example, if you have 10 user licenses, you have 10,000 API calls per day, but one user could use all 10,000 API calls, leaving nothing for the other users. Even those these limits are stated as daily, the limits actually roll off every hour. If you use 1,000 API calls in one hour, 24 hours later, you'll be allowed another 1,000 API calls (the current usage number will be reduced by 1,000).

> I have seen, the maxinum records returned is 2000.

That only applies to the OFFSET keyword. A query may return up to 50,000,000 rows. The API provides a mechanism to pagination through the results in sets of 200-2000 records at a time, based on the Batch Size provided and expected payload size.

Comment: "How many API calls can we make to Salesforce daily?"I asked about API calls from third app to SFDC (users not execute API calls), not the other way around. Thanks

Comment: @Rodolfo If I understand you correctly, we're talking about the same thing. You might have your terminology mixed up.

Comment: So, if a third-party application makes an API Call, following your example, would it count within the limit of 10,000 API Calls? I'm sorry, but it's not clear to me. Thanks

Comment: @Rodolfo Yes, that's correct.